FFmpeg only joins 2 videos of 17
I'm trying to join multiple video files using xfade transitions. But I only get 2 videos joined. What I'm doing wrong ?
ffmpeg \
-i  video0.mp4 \
-i  video1.mp4 \
-i  video10.mp4 \
-i  video11.mp4 \
-i  video12.mp4 \
-i  video13.mp4 \
-i  video14.mp4 \
-i  video15.mp4 \
-i  video16.mp4 \
-i  video17.mp4 \
-i  video18.mp4 \
-i  video2.mp4 \
-i  video4.mp4 \
-i  video5.mp4 \
-i  video6.mp4 \
-i  video7.mp4 \
-i  video8.mp4 \
-filter_complex "\
[0][1]xfade=transition=slidedown:duration=1:offset=4[v1]; \
[v1][2]xfade=transition=pixelize:duration=1:offset=4[v2]; \
[v2][3]xfade=transition=slidedown:duration=1:offset=4[v3]; \
[v3][4]xfade=transition=pixelize:duration=1:offset=4[v4]; \
[v4][5]xfade=transition=slideup:duration=1:offset=4[v5]; \
[v5][6]xfade=transition=slideleft:duration=1:offset=4[v6]; \
[v6][7]xfade=transition=vdslice:duration=1:offset=4[v7]; \
[v7][8]xfade=transition=slideup:duration=1:offset=4[v8]; \
[v8][9]xfade=transition=vdslice:duration=1:offset=4[v9]; \
[v9][10]xfade=transition=wipedown:duration=1:offset=4[v10]; \
[v10][11]xfade=transition=hblur:duration=1:offset=4[v11]; \
[v11][12]xfade=transition=slideup:duration=1:offset=4[v12]; \
[v12][13]xfade=transition=pixelize:duration=1:offset=4[v13]; \
[v13][14]xfade=transition=vdslice:duration=1:offset=4[v14]; \
[v14][15]xfade=transition=slideleft:duration=1:offset=4[v15]; \
[v15][16]xfade=transition=vdslice:duration=1:offset=4[vout] \
" -map "[vout]" joined.mp4

There is no error output, just this:

Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> xfade:main
  Stream #1:0 (h264) -> xfade:xfade
  Stream #2:0 (h264) -> xfade:xfade
  Stream #3:0 (h264) -> xfade:xfade
  Stream #4:0 (h264) -> xfade:xfade
  Stream #5:0 (h264) -> xfade:xfade
  Stream #6:0 (h264) -> xfade:xfade
  Stream #7:0 (h264) -> xfade:xfade
  Stream #8:0 (h264) -> xfade:xfade
  Stream #9:0 (h264) -> xfade:xfade
  Stream #10:0 (h264) -> xfade:xfade
  Stream #11:0 (h264) -> xfade:xfade
  Stream #12:0 (h264) -> xfade:xfade
  Stream #13:0 (h264) -> xfade:xfade
  Stream #14:0 (h264) -> xfade:xfade
  Stream #15:0 (h264) -> xfade:xfade
  Stream #16:0 (h264) -> xfade:xfade
  xfade -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x559d2de188c0] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x559d2de188c0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2 AVX512
[libx264 @ 0x559d2de188c0] profile High 4:4:4 Predictive, level 3.1, 4:4:4, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x559d2de188c0] 264 - core 163 r3060 5db6aa6 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2021 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=4 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'spojeno.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.76.100
  Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv444p(tv, progressive), 1200x670 [SAR 13401:13400 DAR 40203:22445], q=2-31, 25 fps, 12800 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.134.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
frame=  350 fps= 23 q=-1.0 Lsize=    1294kB time=00:00:13.88 bitrate= 763.9kbits/s speed=0.901x
video:1289kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.379462%
[libx264 @ 0x559d2de188c0] frame I:2     Avg QP:19.88  size: 22310
[libx264 @ 0x559d2de188c0] frame P:96    Avg QP:20.30  size:  9926
[libx264 @ 0x559d2de188c0] frame B:252   Avg QP:23.44  size:  1278
[libx264 @ 0x559d2de188c0] consecutive B-frames:  3.7%  0.6%  0.9% 94.9%
[libx264 @ 0x559d2de188c0] mb I  I16..4: 31.2% 60.9%  7.9%
[libx264 @ 0x559d2de188c0] mb P  I16..4:  4.7%  4.2%  1.1%  P16..4: 37.8% 11.6%  7.7%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:32.9%
[libx264 @ 0x559d2de188c0] mb B  I16..4:  0.1%  0.1%  0.1%  B16..8: 38.4%  0.6%  0.0%  direct: 0.1%  skip:60.7%  L0:50.0% L1:49.1% BI: 0.9%
[libx264 @ 0x559d2de188c0] 8x8 transform intra:44.7% inter:82.1%
[libx264 @ 0x559d2de188c0] coded y,u,v intra: 31.0% 10.4% 8.4% inter: 4.9% 1.3% 1.0%
[libx264 @ 0x559d2de188c0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 20% 67%  6%  7%
[libx264 @ 0x559d2de188c0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 23% 37% 23%  2%  3%  2%  3%  2%  5%
[libx264 @ 0x559d2de188c0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 32% 44% 13%  2%  2%  2%  2%  1%  2%
[libx264 @ 0x559d2de188c0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x559d2de188c0] ref P L0: 55.5% 10.2% 24.1% 10.3%
[libx264 @ 0x559d2de188c0] ref B L0: 88.7%  9.2%  2.1%
[libx264 @ 0x559d2de188c0] ref B L1: 96.1%  3.9%
[libx264 @ 0x559d2de188c0] kb/s:754.06


I assume you mean to carry out the xfades at serial intervals i.e. at 4,8,12 ...seconds. In which case, your xfade offsets are wrong. Each successive xfade receives the joined stream from the previous xfade.
It should be
[0][1]xfade=transition=slidedown:duration=1:offset=4[v1]; \
[v1][2]xfade=transition=pixelize:duration=1:offset=8[v2]; \
[v2][3]xfade=transition=slidedown:duration=1:offset=12[v3]; \
...


Yup, you guessed correctly, that has solved my problem. Thank you.
